# DNS lookup failing for sharepoint site?

Tags: dns, sharepoint

I'm trying to browse to a SharePoint Web Front End hosted on a remote machine. I can pull up the machine just fine via Hyper-V and everything seems to be working properly. All of my coworkers sitting around me can browse to the website in question just fine.

I, however, get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."

Opening up Fiddler gives me the following (machine name changed):

```
[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "machineName" failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

When I try to browse directly to the IP of the Web Front End, it appears to have found it as it gives me a login for credentials, but when I use a login that most definitely has full control permissions to the site, I get a `401 Unauthorized` anyway. I've logged in with this user directly from the box without issue as have my coworkers on their machines.

I've tried changing my DNS on my host machine to Google's public DNS without any change.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our sys admin had changed our subnet mask as part of a recent upgrade that was done. Changing it to the new one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a hosts file entry and perform an "ipconfig /flushdns" If that works, you can remove the hosts file entry and try again.